# Sending text and Image simultaneously in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sharing

In my application, My requirement is to send Image and text simultaneously. So I use the following code

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("image/jpeg");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My photos");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///"+f));                       
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

But only the image is sended but the text is not sending. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

plz try this

//assuming uris is a list of Uri

```
Intent intent = null;
if (uris.size > 1){
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
} else if (uris.size() == 1) {
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris.get(0));}
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some message");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"compatible apps:"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the `MIME type` of that `Intent` to `image` that's why only the image is sent.
Something like this will solve your problem:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("*/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My photos");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///"+f));                       
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

Comment: only the file is sended text is not sended by using this

Answer (score 1):

```
String message= "My photos";
URI = Uri.parse("file://" + f);
Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       share.setType("*/*");
       if (URI != null) {
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, URI);
    }
       share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```

This way should be ok.

Comment: only the text is sended file is not sended by using this

Comment: i updated my answer. can you implement and let me know?